# Checking start and end date of different columns in python dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has a date column and 4 other columns that contain numerical values. But each of these other 4 columns start and end at different times. Is there a way in python that I can check start and end date for each column? 
Here's an example of my dataframe:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({
'Date': [1930, 1931, 1932, 1933,1934],
'File1': [np.nan, 72, 58, 280, 958],
'File2': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 13, 89],
'File3': [np.nan, 55, 68, 18, np.nan],
'File4': [45, 552, 177, np.nan, np.nan]
})
```

So for example i want to extract/know the start and end date for file 3 (in this case it should return 1931 and 1933).

If there's a way i can know the start and end date for all files that will be even better.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like that:

```
column_search='File2'
df_search=df[df[column_search].notnull()]
print(f"start date: {df_search['Date'].min()} ")
print(f"end date: {df_search['Date'].max()}")
```

According to your comment:
To iterate trough columns:

```
for column in df.columns:
    df_search=df[df[column].notnull()]
    print(f"start date: {df_search['Date'].min()} ")
    print(f"end date: {df_search['Date'].max()}")
```

if Date column is Index of the df:

```
for column in df.columns:
    idx_list=df.index[df[column].notnull()].tolist() 
    print(f"start date: {min(idx_list)} ")
    print(f"end date: {max(idx_list)} ")
```

Comment: this worked, but is there a way i can recursively do this? i.e getting the start and end for all columns in the dataframe? Also, if i set my date column to index this method doesnt work, is there a way i could use index to check start and end date for the columns?

Answer (score 0):

No need for explicity loops over columns, you can just use "apply".

This would give you a dictionary where the key is the file name and the values are the start and end date as a list:

```
df = df.set_index('Date')
result_dict = {}
def check_date(column):
    x = column.notnull()
    print(type(column[x]))
    result_dict[column.name] = [column[x].head(1).index[0], 
    column[x].tail(1).index[0]]
df.apply(check_date)
print(result_dict)
```

I get this result:

```
{'File1': [1931, 1934], 'File2': [1933, 1934], 'File3': [1931, 1933], 'File4': [1930, 1932]}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this gives the following error `NameError: ("name 'result_dict' is not defined", 'occurred at index  File1')`

Comment: You are right, the declaration of the dictionary was not in the code. Should be fixed now.